# Inserting a variable in php-fpm.conf

Tags: php, config, fpm

I'd like to add the `date` to the name of my slow log file (to make like a rotating log).

I can't find a way to do it like this in my `php-fpm.conf`. The server doesn't restart with the date. Is this even possible to accomplish this way?

```
[www]
date = $(date +"%Y-%m-%d")
slowlog = /var/www/html/perf/slow-$date.log
request_slowlog_timeout = 3s
```

Comment: You should look at [`logrotate`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate). This tool will rotate the log files, without requiring to tweak some conf files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't add changeable variables to php-fpm.conf , it's not a PHP file, it's basically a text file